# Inconsistent primefaces commandbutton behaviour

Tags: autocomplete, primefaces

Using the following code I get an behaviour that I can't explain.

The autocomplete method works fine to select an object.
It updates the panel below as expected.

But then the two buttons (New Airport, Save Airport) are not firing the backing bean listener.
However if I click on one of the buttons *before* using the autocomplete to load an object, the listener gets fired.

```
<h:form id="arptForm">
            <p:autoComplete minQueryLength="3"
                value="#{airportHandler.theAirportNames}" effect="fade"
                completeMethod="#{airportHandler.autoComplete}"
                forceSelection="true" converter="airportNamesConverter"
                var="airport" itemLabel="#{airport.icaoName}" itemValue="#{airport}"
                maxResults="#{airportHandler.maxAutoCompleteResults}">
                <f:ajax event="itemSelect"
                    listener="#{airportHandler.airportChanged}" render="@form" />
                <p:column style="width:80%">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{airport.icaoName} - #{airport.iataName} - #{airport.airportName} (#{airport.cityName})" />
                </p:column>
            </p:autoComplete>
            <p:spacer width="20" height="20" />
            <p:commandButton id="newAirport" value="New Airport"
                icon="ui-icon-newwin" actionListener="#{airportHandler.newAirport}"
                update="@form" />
            <p:spacer width="20" height="20" />
            <p:commandButton id="saveAirport" value="Save Airport"
                icon="ui-icon-newwin" actionListener="#{airportHandler.saveAirport}"/>
            <p:separator />

            <p:outputPanel id="allArptData">

                <p:panel id="airportBasics" header="Airport Basics"
                    toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500"
                    rendered="#{airportHandler.theAirport != null}">
                    <ui:include src="airportbasics.xhtml" />
                </p:panel>

                <p:panel id="airportRunways" header="Airport Runways"
                    toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500"
                    rendered="#{airportHandler.theAirport != null}">
                    <ui:include src="airportrunways.xhtml" />
                </p:panel>


            </p:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
```

Can you explain what happens ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you put your buttons into a different `form`? Warn me if it works please.

Comment: Nested forms are not good practice if I read well. So what should UI do ? a form for the auto complete, a form the each buttons, and what about the remaining components (no forms ?)

Comment: I am not saying nest them, just put them into different forms. If that works I am going to explain with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you should not the nest forms that is not correct. Also when you put everything inside a one main `form` that means you are mixing the processes while submitting that form. There can be lot's of forms per a page like autocomplete form or profile information form etc.

When you do sth. about autocomplete actually you want to submit things about autocomplete not about other buttons so simply seperate them. That does not mean you should have forms for each component but just seperate your page into main sections.

Comment: You are welcome. I really suggest you to read BalusC's blog to learn basics deeply, about JSF. [Here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)